# blit an array of images in pygame

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

I´m doing an easy game where I want to display some imgs at random locations with their respective rects, heres my code:

```
class Juego1:
    def __init__(self, next_scene):
        self.background = pygame.Surface(size)
        self.imagenes1_array = ['autobus.png','coche.png','barco.png','autobus2.png','grua.png','bici.png']
        for i in self.imagenes1_array:
            self.imagenes1 = pygame.image.load(i)
            self.imagenes1_rect = self.imagenes1.get_rect()
            self.imagenes1_rect = self.imagenes1_rect.move(random.randint(0,1600),random.randint(0,900))
        
    def start(self, gamestate):
        self.gamestate = gamestate
        
       
    def draw(self,screen):
        self.background = pygame.Surface(size)
        x = random.randint(0,1600)
        y = random.randint(0,900)
        coordinates = (x,y)
        for i in self.imagenes1_array:
            imagenes1 = pygame.image.load(i).convert()
            screen.blit(imagenes1,x,y)

    
    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    return (self.next_scene, None)
```

but it keeps sending me this error:
**invalid destination position for blit**

What am I doing wrong?
Also, I don´t know think the way I´m trying to display both, img load and rects of the image array is good so let me know thanks

Here is the full code:

```
# Importamos las librerías necesarias
import sys, pygame, pygame.freetype, random
from pygame.locals import *

size = 1600, 900

# Colours    R    G    B
GRAY     = (100, 100, 100)
NAVYBLUE = ( 60,  60, 100)
BLACK    = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = (255, 255, 255)
RED      = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN    = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE     = (  0,   0, 255)
YELLOW   = (255, 255,   0)
ORANGE   = (255, 128,   0)
PURPLE   = (127,   0, 255)
CYAN     = (  0, 255, 255)

class PrimeraEscena:

    def __init__(self, next_scene):
        self.background = pygame.Surface(size)

        self.flechaImg = pygame.image.load('flecha.png')
        self.flechaImg_rect = self.flechaImg.get_rect()
        self.flechaImg_rect = self.flechaImg_rect.move(1300,600)

        self.next_scene = next_scene
        
    def draw(self,screen):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",90)
        img = font.render('Memory',True, PURPLE)
        screen.blit(img, (620,400)) 
        screen.blit(self.flechaImg, (1300,600))
    
    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = event.pos
                if self.flechaImg_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    return (self.next_scene, None)


class Juego1:
    def __init__(self, next_scene):
        self.background = pygame.Surface(size)
        
        self.images = []
        self.rects = []
        self.imagenes1_array = ['autobus.png','coche.png','barco.png','autobus2.png','grua.png','bici.png']
        for i in self.imagenes1_array:
            self.images.append(pygame.image.load(i))
            s = pygame.Surface((20,20))
            self.rects.append(s.get_rect())

        print(self.images)
        print(self.imagenes1_array)
        

    def start(self, gamestate):
        self.gamestate = gamestate
        for rect in self.rects:
            x = random.randint(300,1000)
            y = random.randint(200,700)
            rect.x = x
            rect.y = y
        
       
    def draw(self,screen):
        self.background = pygame.Surface(size)
        
        for i in range(len(self.images)):
            screen.blit(self.images[i], (self.rects[i].x, self.rects[i].y))
        
    
    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for rect in self.rects:
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        print('works!')

def main():
    # Inicializamos pygame
    pygame.init()
    
    # Definimos las dimensiones de la ventana (1600 x 900px) y reloj
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Ponemos el título e icono y fondo de la ventana
    pygame.display.set_caption("Quiz Game")
    icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    fondoImg = pygame.image.load('fondo_memory.png')

    dt = 0
    scenes = {
        'PORTADA': PrimeraEscena('SEGUNDA'),
        'SEGUNDA': Juego1('SEGUNDA'),


    }
    scene = scenes['PORTADA']
    # Comenzamos el bucle del juego
    run=True
    while run:
        # RGB - Red, Green, Blue
        screen.fill ((255,255,255))
        
        # Imagen fondo
        screen.blit(fondoImg, (0,0))

        # Eventos del mouse 
        events = pygame.event.get()

        # Capturamos los eventos que se han producido
        for event in events:
            
            # Definimos eventos:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # Si el evento es salir de la ventana, terminamos
                run = False
            
        result = scene.update(events, dt)
        if result:
            next_scene, state = result
            if next_scene:
                scene = scenes[next_scene]
                scene.start(state)
        scene.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)
        #pygame.display.update()
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the loaded images to a list, you just call load, assign it, and then go again.  You shouldn't be loading the images in draw. Load them to a list in init, and then iterate through the list in draw.

init:

```
self.images = []
self.imagenes1_array = ['autobus.png','coche.png','barco.png','autobus2.png','grua.png','bici.png']
        for i in self.imagenes1_array:
            self.images.append(pygame.image.load(i))
```

draw:

```
def draw(self,screen):
        self.background = pygame.Surface(size)
        x = random.randint(0,1600)
        y = random.randint(0,900)
        coordinates = (x,y)
        for i in self.images:
            screen.blit(i, (x,y))
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, but it keeps displaying all the images at once on the same spot at random places (obv, cuz i wanted random coordenates), but it doesnt stop and I want to display all 6 images and make it a day.

Comment: move the x and y random co-ordinates part inside the for loop.

Comment: I did it and now it displays all images, but it keeps having the same problem of displaying on an eternal loop. I think its because the random.randint that doesnt stop generating coordenates but it shouldnt be like that right? In my head, it should generate both random coordinates for each element on self.images (6 elements), instead keeps generating and doesnt stop, idk how to solve it

Comment: There is nothing in the code provided that would cause the draw function to be repeatedly called, so it must be elsewhere. How is it called? Can you post the full code somewhere?

Comment: You are calling draw in the run loop, so it is repeatedly calling draw and making new images and co-ordinates.

Comment: oh true, but if I remove the draw, my PrimeraEscena doesnt run the draws and stuff, i dont really know how the scenes work or why my first scene is not working if i dont put that scene.draw at the beginning. Any clue?

Comment: I moved the random to start.  I had to comment out the images and use surfaces as I don't have the images http://pastie.org/p/7yr1cFXbdOCCKS3ihBRbdE

Comment: I am on reddit, same name as here but with 2 at the end, so you can msg me on there if you want to. You will see my comments on the pygame sub, https://old.reddit.com/r/pygame/

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument oh [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is a a pair of coordinates (e.g. tuple or list) with the position:

<s>`screen.blit(imagenes1,x,y)`</s>

```py
screen.blit(imagenes1, (x, y))
```

Comment: Oh thanks, now it shows something, but something i didnt expected.

Comment: It shows only the first image of the array and its appearing at random places all the time, uncontrollable, how can I do to blit the 6 images only and stay at random places?